# I want to get the root folder in a Path which is stored in a variable using groovy and used this root value in if statement

Tags: if-statement, groovy

I want to get the root folder in a Path which is stored in a variable.

```
b="Sports/Badminton/Players/Saina.txt"
```

Now i want to copy the file if root is "Sports".

```
if (b=="Sports")
{
 (new AntBuilder()).copy(file:  ("$gitPath/$b"), tofile:  ("$ServerPath/$b"))  

        }

        else { println "unknown file" }
```

Now this will always execute the else statement as condition in if statement was not properly written.So i want the correct way to write the condition so that it only takes the value of b when the root folder is Sports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to check for an actual folder or file on the filesystem, there are a couple simple string methods you can use to solve this.

```
b.startsWith("Sports")
```

or

```
b.tokenize("/")[0] == "Sports"
```